# Transferlearning ResNet Model does not learn

Tags: python-3.x, keras, computer-vision, resnet, transfer-learning

I trained ResNet-50 model to classify images from 6 classes (my own dataset) and saved it. But the model did not learn properly and predictions are incorrect. What would be the reason for this poor learning?
Here is my code, and the output plots using Keras and TensorFlow backend. How can I solve this?

```
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, image
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGE = True

# Define some constant needed throughout the script
N_CLASSES = 6
EPOCHS = 20
PATIENCE = 5
TRAIN_PATH= '/Train/'
VALID_PATH = '/Test/'
MODEL_CHECK_WEIGHT_NAME = 'resnet_monki_v1_chk.h5'



# Define model to be used we freeze the pre trained resnet model weight, and add few layer on top of it to utilize our custom dataset
K.set_learning_phase(0)
model = ResNet50(input_shape=(224,224,3),include_top=False, weights='imagenet', pooling='avg')
K.set_learning_phase(1)
x = model.output
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
output = Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='softmax', name='custom_output')(x)
custom_resnet = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs = output)

for layer in model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

custom_resnet.compile(Adam(lr=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
custom_resnet.summary()



# 4. Load dataset to be used
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
traingen = datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_PATH, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
validgen = datagen.flow_from_directory(VALID_PATH, target_size=(224,224), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical', shuffle=False)


# 5. Train Model we use ModelCheckpoint to save the best model based on validation accuracy
es_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=PATIENCE, mode='max')
mc_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=MODEL_CHECK_WEIGHT_NAME, monitor='val_acc', save_best_only=True, mode='max')
train_history = custom_resnet.fit_generator(traingen, steps_per_epoch=len(traingen), epochs= EPOCHS, validation_data=traingen, validation_steps=len(validgen), verbose=2, callbacks=[es_callback, mc_callback])


custom_resnet.save('custom_resnet.h5')
```

Here are the plots, I had to put the links, the site does not let me put a pic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DybOV.png)

Comment: The learning curves look fine, what makes you say that it is not learning?

Comment: I am actually classifying cars based on their color. Car images are taking in real-world conditions in which the background changes. After training when I test it, the estimation is wrong most of the time.

Comment: Where is the code that produces those predictions?